# How to fill all the lines containing the same reference code

Tags: excel, vba

I've created an inventory manager.
On each line you find several information but most importantly the ticket number.
If a ticket contains several articles, you will have several lines with the same ticket number.

[image]
[image]

Is there a VBA code to indicate I would like all the lines containing the selected ticket number in my userform to be filled with the date ? I would then only have to select the reference in the userform and all the lines with this ticket number would be filled.

For now I only have this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim k As Long


If Me.Cbx_ticket.ListIndex >= 0 Then
       'Ask for validation
    If MsgBox("Voulez-vous valider le DT ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

            
    'Display information in database DT
    With Sheets("DT")
            k = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cbx_ticket, .Range("I:I"), 0)
            .Range("K" & k) = CDate(Now())
    End With
```

Thanks a lot.

Best,

Comment: Not clear what you want accomplishing. At least, for me... Do all the time a specific Ticked is associated with the same Client? If not, should the two parameters be taken in consideration in order to identify all the necessary rows? Are the sheet sorted? Are the lines in discussion consecutive?

Comment: Do you really need help?

Comment: Ok. You have one return ticket which can concern several equipments (in this case, it's about renting equipment). Each line concerns one equipment that is linked to a ticket number. If one client needs 3 equipments, you will have 3 lines with the same ticket number. my question is : what code do I need to tell Excel to put today's date in all lines containing the same ticket number. So in Commandbutton2, if you select DT-029, I want all the lines concerning this ticket number to have the date cell filled with today's date. Is it clearer ? My code only works for one line...